# Update and republish wordpress post. SEO penalization?

Tags: seo, google, wordpress, publishing

I'm currently working on improving some old posts, adding content, notes and so... I plan to publish them again on every update so it is showed again in the homescreen with the new date.

Do you know if this can be punished by google in anyway?

I already know that google punishes when the same content is republished, but if it gets updated... what happens?

Comment: If you update your posts, that is exactly the kind of activity that Google likes. Just make sure that there are no duplicates, that is, the old post and a new post. Make sure you are updating the old post and you should actually be rewarded for it!

Answer (score 1):

This should not result in any spam penalties from Google.  You are not creating duplicate content - the post still exists only once on the site - so the only issue will be how Google recalculates the page based on the republished content.